# ASP.Net DropDownList SelectedIndex not changing

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am working on a project where I have an OdbcDataReader that reads in the data from a query and populates a DropDownList with the items from the query. When I run the web app and choose different items in the list the selected value never changes whether postback is enabled or not, the smartpaging is enabled, or if the EnableViewState

```
 protected void populateGrid(OdbcDataReader reader)
    {
        ClientDropDownList.DataSource = reader;
        ClientDropDownList.DataTextField = "company";
        ClientDropDownList.DataBind();

    }
```

Comment: Please provide some more information. 
Which page lifecycle stage are you using to invoke this **populateGrid(...)** method? If you want to get the selected value in the code behind, what method are you using to do this?

Comment: You should also set the [DataValueField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datavaluefield.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you should set the AutoPostBack = true for the Dropdownlist control.

Second thing is You should bind the values in the Page_Load event by checking Ispostback

```
If(! IsPostBack())   
{

    Bind your dropdownlist  here.
}
```

Thrid thing is As per the Asp.Net Life cycle process.Page load will fire every time.When ever the page getting refresh.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you are not calling `PopulateGrid` on each `PostBack`.  One of the most common issues people run into.

If your calling `PopulateGrid` in your `Page_Load` wrap it in a `if (!IsPostBack)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
  foreach (ListItem item in YourDropDownList.Items)
     {
            if (item.Text == defaultText) 
            {
                item.Selected = true;
                break;
            }
     }
```